# Python beginner here. Why does the following code cause a TypeError?

Tags: python, list, integer

Does anyone know why this results in a TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'?

```
user_input = input("Please enter a list of numbers here: ")
lst4 = user_input.split()

def sum67(lst4):
    segment_one = []
    segment_two = []
    for i in range(len(lst4)):
        if int(lst4[i]) == 6:
            segment_one.append(int(lst4[0:i]))
    for i2 in range(len(lst4)):
        if int(lst4[i2]) == 7 and i2 > len(segment_one):
            segment_two.append (int(lst4[i2+1:])) 
    complete_list = segment_one + segment_two
    total = 0 
    for groups in complete_list:
        for value in groups:
            total += value

    return total   

print(sum67(lst4))
```

Here is the full input and error message:

```
Please enter a list of numbers here: 2 3 4 6 7 8

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lucasjacaruso/Desktop/Calc Course/Powers_list.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(sum67(lst4))    
  File "/Users/lucasjacaruso/Desktop/Calc Course/Powers_list.py", line 9, in sum67
    segment_one.append(int(lst4[0:i]))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please also post your error message as text.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your posted code hangs waiting for input: *you* are suppsed to provide that (use an assignment statement, not `input`), as well as the *full* error message.

Comment: Please enter a list of numbers here: "2 3 4 6 7 8" ?

Answer (score 2):

All because of this parts of your code:

```
segment_one.append(int(lst4[0:i]))


segment_two.append (int(lst4[i2+1:]))
```

lst4[0:i] returns list, but int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number as it is said in the error message. Same with lst4[i2+1:].

For example if your input is '10 11 6 12', then lst4[0:i] returns [10, 11]. And if you try to call:

```
int([10, 11])
```

you'll get the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't account for malformed input like alphanumeric input and multiple spaces. 
Your second line can be as shown below. Also, you won't have to do int conversion later on, since your lst4 will be a list of ints by default

```
lst4 = [int(i) for i in user_input.split(" ") if i.isdigit()]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Much appreciated.